# Find the image of the region $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: 0\leq Re(z) \leq 1/2,\; -\pi \leq Im(z) \leq \pi\}$ under the mapping $w=e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have no clue if I am doing this correctly, just basing it off what my teacher did for a similar example.

I look at image of $y=a$

$u(x,y) = e^x \cos{a}$

$v(x,y) = e^x \sin{a}$

$$y=-\pi ,    f(z) = u+iv = -e^x <0$$
 $$y=\pi ,    f(z) = u+iv = -e^x <0$$

So this is below the x-axis, I am confused on how to apply this to the Re(z) boundary if this method is even correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = a+ib \in \mathbb{C}$.
Then $Re(z) = a$, $Im(z) = b$ and $0 \leq a \leq 1/2$, $-\pi \leq b \leq \pi$.
We know that $e^z = e^{a+ib} = e^a(\cos(b) + i\sin(b))$.
So, if we fix $a = 0$, for example, we have $e^a = 1$ and we are left with $\cos(b) + i\sin(b)$, where $-\pi \leq b \leq \pi$.
So, if this is the range of $b$, what figure you obtain?

Now note that for every other $a$ you fix, you will obtain the same figure, but with a small difference.
What's this difference?